# Form A not updating values in Form B

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 forms. Lets call the FormA and FormB. When  a button is pressed in FormA I open formB from FormA. Then I call  a function inside FormB that is supposed to update the text fields. When I do this none of the textboxes are filled with values, even though values are being assigned to them ( i can see this in debug mode).

But when I put the same code in the form_load event handler it works fine. Any ideas?

This is FormAs code:

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click()
[Form_Client Info].Modal = False
Call DoCmd.OpenForm("Client Info")
Call [Form_Client Info].SetValues(lstClients.Column(0, intIndex))
End Sub
```

and this is FormBs:

```
Public Sub SetValues(ByVal intID As Long)
Dim arrFields(0 To 8) As Variant
Dim arrValues(0 To 8) As Variant

For i = 1 To 9
    arrFields(i - 1) = General.GetField(i, "Clients")
Next i
Call General.GetRecord2(arrFields, arrValues, "Clients")

txtPOBOX.Value = 3434 'arrValues(0)
txtFirstName.Value = arrValues(1)
txtLastName.Value = arrValues(2)
txtPhoneNumber.Value = arrValues(3)
txtStartDate.Value = arrValues(4)
txtEndDate.Value = arrValues(5)
cmbPlan.Value = arrValues(6)
cmbDuration.Value = arrValues(7)
txtPhoneBalance.Value = arrValues(8)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have this line:

```
[Form_Client Info].Modal = False
```

it sounds like your form is saved as modal.

Try to specify the non-modal status when opening it:

```
Call DoCmd.OpenForm("Client Info", , , , , acWindowNormal)
```